# Centering table on a page on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center a table using bootstrap.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table id="total votes" class="table table-hover text-centered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Total votes</th>
                <th> = </th>
                <th>Voter A</th>
                <th> + </th>
                <th>Voter B</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ total_votes }}</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td>{{ total_voter_a }}</td>
                <td> + </td>
                <td>{{ total_voter_b }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

However, no matter how I adjust the `css`, the table is still aligned to the left. I'm sure I am missing something simple. I also thought `container-fluid` would make the table span across the whole page.

here is the css:

```
.table th {
    text-align: center;
}

.table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the contents of each of the cell of the table should align center?

Comment: how about wrapping the table in a `div` with the class `textcentered` ?

Comment: Normally yes the 'container fluid'  will do that but your table must also have his width to be set to 100% . You can wrap it in a div and style this with 'margin: 0 auto'

Comment: This way works without changing the size of your table & regardless of screen size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270709/10415078

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're missing the `margin:auto`

```
.table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: none;
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/KVdYep)

Comment: My problem was that I had a lot of divs around the table

Comment: This way works without changing the size of your table & regardless of screen size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270709/10415078

Answer (score 6):

Change your CSS to:

```
table{
   margin: 0 auto
}
```