# How do I horizontally center a table in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This my code. What I'm trying to do is to get this table at the center of the container. But instead, it aligns to the left by default when I use the "container" class, and it uses the full width when I use the "container-fluid class" for the div. I want to horizontally center the table. Can anyone help?

```
<!-- Container (Pricing Section) -->
<div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead><tr>
<th>Material Name</th>
<th>Rate (INR)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="">
<tr>
<td>Books</td>
<td>7.00(per KG)</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Soft Plastic</td>
<td>15.00(per KG)</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hard Plastic</td>
<td>2.00(per KG)</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I know "container-fluid" uses the full width, but I have also used "container" class only and it does not help. Please advise.

Answer (score 88):

Using this Bootstrap row/column combination works regardless of the size of your table or screen, no CSS necessary:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        ....table stuff....
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is for bootstrap 4.

Comment: I think you'd have to make sure the table width does not exceed the screen width, as it will remain centered, with no scrollbar. Either that or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: col-md-4, col-md-6 etc can be applied according to table size.

Answer (score 28):

To horizontally center the table itself, you can use in a CSS, both the `margin` and `width` properties.

```
.table {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50% !important; 
}
```

Now, for the content of the table, you can use both a combination of CSS and the Bootstrap typography classes. In this case, CSS for the `th` elements, and the `.text-center` class in your table.

```
table th {
   text-align: center; 
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
    <!-- Content of the table -->
</table>
```

Here your can see it for both `.container-fluid` and `.container` classes:

```css
table th {
   text-align: center; 
}

.table {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50% !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- container-fluid -->
<div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Material Name</th>
          <th>Rate (INR)</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Books</td>
           <td>7.00(per KG)</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Soft Plastic</td>
           <td>15.00(per KG)</td>
       </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Hard Plastic</td>
       <td>2.00(per KG)</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
  
<!-- container -->
<div id="pricing" class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Material Name</th>
          <th>Rate (INR)</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Books</td>
           <td>7.00(per KG)</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Soft Plastic</td>
           <td>15.00(per KG)</td>
       </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Hard Plastic</td>
       <td>2.00(per KG)</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is a poor man's solution to get into the CSS and add some code. The reason why stylesheets such as bootstrap are so complete is precisely to avoid hacking the css.

Comment: Biggest withdrawal with this solution is the width of the table, what if we don't want it to be only 50%? Kat provided a great answer now compatible with latest bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 20):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="mx-auto w-auto">
      ....
    </table>
</div>
```

Take solution from [Center bootstrap table with 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454546/548473)
Comment from @Rene Hamburger: as in the linked answer, `w-auto` is required for the table to keep its original, natural width. Otherwise it's resized to 100%.

Answer (score 6):

Just add a class: `text-center` in table class.

```
<table class="table text-center"> 
... 
</table>
```

It's a native class from Bootstrap that permits horizontal align.

Comment: It's making the cells center-aligned

Answer (score 3):

You can center the table as follows with `CSS`.

```
.table {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

You need to have `margin: auto`

Comment: There is no need to add css. Hacking the css should be the last option but unfortunately for some it is the first reflex. The reason why large stylesheet frameworks like bootstrap were created is precisely to provide a full solution that does not require coding css except for cosmetic stuff like colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try column classes make it center

```
<div class="row col-md-4 col-md-push-4"><!-- you can use column classes md-3,md-5 as per your table width -->
<table class="yourtableclasses">
<!-- table content -->
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

With css

```
.table td {
   text-align: center;   
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8s9918my/

Or bootstrap:

```
<table class="table text-center">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. The table is still on the left.

Answer (score -1):

Use `mx-auto` to horizontally center the table...

```
<div class='col-5 mx-auto'>
    <table class='table'>
        ...   
    </table>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='col-5 mx-auto'>
    <table class='table'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John Doe</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jane Smith</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mark Johnson</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```